# Different accuracies for different algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart, algorithms

I have a binary classification dataset with all features in numeric form. Most of them are continuous variable (within ranges, for example - from 2.50001 to 2.9999).

I want to predict the output which is a binary classification (0 or 1).

I used many classification algorithm but decision tree works the best. I would like to know why this is good and why others are bad? There is a little difference between the training and testing accuracies for all the algorithms, so there wont be any overfitting.

[image]

I would like to hear some experts advices here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: 
[Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
[Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)
[Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision tree are extremely efficient, very easy to tune and can handle non-linearity extremely well.

Adaboost and RandomForest should be better than Decision Tree but they might be overfitting a bit.

If the exemple of feature is correct and you have that many precision digits, then all the more for Trees because they can split on specific values that would be characteristic of your binary outcome. For instance they could split 2.50001 from 2.50000.

Now Neural Network can be as good as trees but they are a lot harder to fine tune and that could explain your result. Usually on small to medium tabular data, Decision Tree (Xgboost for intance) will outperform Neural Net. Or put it differently it would take a very large amount of time to fine tune NN to match Gradient Boosted trees.

Finally, SVM is very inefficient and linear by default. So except if you set the kernel to a non-linear one like RBF, this result is completely expected.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy it answers your question. Could you note my post as the correct answer ? thanks you :)

Comment: Could you advice me one more thing. Why would the decision tree give different accuracies everytime we run it using the same data.

Comment: Hard to answer without your code, but there are some implementation that are non deterministic (include randomness in the selection of column, splits etc...) so each run could be slightly different

Comment: Thanks. I understood now